# grouping and averaging fixed range of numbers in R

Tags: r, range, grouping

I have range of numbers with scores. I want to calculate average of fixed length ranges between rows.(find fixed ranges and averaging)
let's say: `df1:`

```
start   end    score
100     105     2.2
105     110     2.4
110     115     2.6
130     135     1.4
135     140     1.2
200     205     5.0
205     210     5.8
210     215     5.4
```

I want to make such table: `df2`

```
start   end   avg
100     115   2.4
130     140   1.3
200     215   5.4
```

The fixed range refers to difference between rows;ex: In the first 3 rows of `df1` the differenece is `5 (100-105-110)` and then in row `4` it jumps into `130`. Thus, the detected continuous range is from `100 to 115`)

I would thankful if you tell me how can I do it in R.

Comment: What are these "fixed length ranges"? How are you supposed to infer them from the data? Your example doesn't seem to have a uniform window size.

Comment: @MrFlick, I mean while the difference between rows is the same (here is 5) take average. The first 3 rows of `df1$start` are successive but in  4th row it jumps from 110 to 130, because the difference is not 5.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

One way would be to try `dplyr`.  Here, we create a grouping variable `grp` based on whether the difference between current and succeeding row of `start` is greater than `5` or not (`diff(start)>5`) using `cumsum` after concatenating with `TRUE` as the `diff` output would be shorter in length by `1` than the `nrow(df)`.  After we did the grouping `group_by(...)`, use `summarise` and select the first value of `start` (`start[1]`) per `grp`, last value of `end` (`end[n()]`) and the `mean` of score.  `n()` gives the `nrow(.)` for the grouped subsets.

```
library(dplyr)
df %>% 
   group_by(grp=cumsum(c(TRUE, diff(start)>5))) %>%
   summarise(start=start[1], end=end[n()], score=mean(score))%>%
   select(-grp) #as suggested by @MrFlick
#  start end score
#1   100 115   2.4
#2   130 140   1.3
#3   200 215   5.4
```

Or using `data.table`.  Here, also, we are summarising the results in a `list`.  Instead of `n()`, the syntax is `.N`.

```
library(data.table)
setDT(df)[,list(start=start[1], end=end[.N], score=mean(score)) ,
                        by=list(grp=cumsum(c(TRUE, diff(start)>5)))]
```

Or using `base R`

```
 do.call(rbind,by(df, list(grp=cumsum(c(TRUE, diff(df$start)>5))), 
      FUN= function(x) with(x,c(start=start[1], end=end[nrow(x)],
                                          score=mean(score)))))
 #   start end score
 #1   100 115   2.4
 #2   130 140   1.3
 #3   200 215   5.4
```

#### data

```
df <- structure(list(start = c(100L, 105L, 110L, 130L, 135L, 200L, 
 205L, 210L), end = c(105L, 110L, 115L, 135L, 140L, 205L, 210L, 
 215L), score = c(2.2, 2.4, 2.6, 1.4, 1.2, 5, 5.8, 5.4)), .Names = c("start", 
 "end", "score"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -8L))
```

Comment: You could also add a `%>% select(-grp)` to get rid of the temp variable.

Comment: @akrun thanks for your answer. but i received error: in the first: `Error in n() : This function should not be called directly` . and in the second: `Error in x[0L] : object of type 'closure' is not subsettable`. I cant understand where the problem is.

Comment: @Cina I am using `dplyr_0.3`.  Please check the version you have.  Regarding the second error, could you show the `dput` of a very small dataset, that shows this error.  I updated the post with the `dput` output.  Could you test it on that dataset?

Comment: perfect,  thanks. I just needed to edit my real df. my final `dput` is:`... , .Names = c("start", "end", "score"),class="data.frame", row.names = c(NA,-240573L))`. anyway, could you explain a bit about `summarise(start=start[1], end=end[n()])` and  `list(start=start[1], end=end[.N])`?. thanks again

Comment: @Cina A partial `dput` output is not useful.  If you paste that in the console, it will only end up in error.  I will add the explanation in the post.

Comment: first 10 elements of df(V2 is start, V3 is end and V4 is score: `structure(list(V1 = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L), .Label = "chr2", class = "factor"), V2 = c(263550L, 
263650L, 263675L, 263700L, 263725L, 263775L, 263800L, 266200L, 
266225L, 266250L), V3 = c(263575L, 263675L, 263700L, 263725L, 
263750L, 263800L, 263825L, 266225L, 266250L, 266275L), V4 = c(10.56, 
11.12, 11.84, 12.52, 11.56, 10.76, 10.2, 11, 10.84, 10)), .Names = c("V1", 
"V2", "V3", "V4"), class = c("data.table", "data.frame"), row.names = c(NA, 
-10L), .internal.selfref = <pointer: 0x0000000004750788>)`

Comment: @Cina Using the dput output (excluding the `.internal..`), your `df` is already a `data.table` with `10 rows`. Based on the condition, there will be again 10 groups.  So, there won't be any summarisation in this dataset,   `df[, cumsum(c(TRUE, diff(V2)>5))]
 [1]  1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9 10`

Comment: @akrun my df is huge i can only copy the last part which is `.Names = c("V1", "V2", "V3", "V4"), class = c("data.table", 
"data.frame"), row.names = c(NA, -240573L)`. Is it informative enough? thanks for all your help.

Comment: @Cina Yes, I understand.  But, this dataset doesn't give any errors and the groupings based on `>5` gives each unique group for the 10 rows.

Comment: actually the real data based on `25`. could you correct me here : `new_me1 %>% 
     group_by(grp=cumsum(c(TRUE, diff(V2)>25))) %>%
     summarise(V2=V2[1], V3=V3[n()], V4=mean(V4))%>%
     select(-grp)` . V2 is start and V3 is end and V4 is the score in the example.

Comment: @Cina Convert the `data.table` to `data.frame` and use the same code.  If you are using recent versions of `data.table` use `setDF(new_me1)` or else `new_me1 <- as.data.frame(new_me1)`.  Yes, I was able to replicate the error before converting it. `Error in n() : This function should not be called directly`.  It works after the conversion.

Comment: @akrun, well done, thanks so much. After converting to data frame it works correctly. no error. thanks again.